# noscript - can I load a different page?

Tags: javascript, noscript

I have a page that is very javascript dependent for functionality.  Basically - 90% of my services won't work without javascript.  What I really want to do is detect if javascript is disabled, and then direct users to a page with information about enabling javascript or downloading an updated browser.  Does anybody have advice for the easiest way to accomplish this?  I don't want users to even attempt using my app if they aren't using javascript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go about it the other way. Start outputting the "noscript" page by default, and have some JS redirects the user to the enhanced page automatically.

That way, JS-deprived users automatically get the "hey, you're on a brain dead browser" page, and JS-enabled people get the funky enhanced version.

Comment: Hi Mark,  I was thinking about this, but will it have a negative impact on SEO?

Comment: SEO's meaningless if you go the other way - You can't redirect non-JS people on the enhanced page without JS so there they are, stuck on a fancy page they can't use.

Answer (score 0):

You could include a message inside `<noscript></noscript>` tags; this will be shown to users without JS enabled but hidden for people who have it.

EDIT: Having just this moment realized you were probably talking about the `<noscript>` tags and not the NoScript Firefox extension, you could try putting a `<meta>` tag to redirect and use JS to remove this; browsers without JS will get the tag and redirect while JS-enabled browsers shouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

This will directly redirect the user when JavaScript is disabled:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <noscript>
      <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://www.example.com/no-javascript/" />
    </noscript>
  </head>

  <body>
    JavaScript is enabled!
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes, but JS can't disable the meta refresh and the page will STILL redirect even though the user's on a 'good' browser.

Comment: This doesn't work on Chromium 113, it redirects although JS is enabled. On Firefox 115, it doesn't redirect even if disable JS using an addon.